# Creating and using dynamic libraries in OS X

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dylib, dynamic-library

We have a Windows application written in C++, part of which we are trying to port to Mac OS X. Our goal is to wrap the business logic into some libraries and build a Cocoa layer on top for the controller and the GUI. We will probably have several smaller apps using the same libraries so our first thought was to use dynamic libraries for the C++ code (unless there is a better way).
However, we are having some problems with achieving this. Our dynamic library complies fine (at least it looks like that) and we get a .dylib file which we link to in our app. The problem is that our app simply can't find any of the .h files we are trying to include.
We have already checked that the .h files are being exported as well as checked the install name and made sure that the library is located in the correct directory. Also, we have followed Apple's guide for creating and using dynamic libraries and found no special step we were missing.

My question here is in two parts:

1. Is there some obvious step we might be missing which is instrumental in exposing the interface (i.e. the .h files) that we should try before anything else?
2. We do suspect that the fault might be in the crappy C++ code we have inherited in this project. For instance, there is a lot of logic (implementation of methods) written directly in .h files and in some cases there isn't even a corresponding .cpp file at all. So the .h files aren't merely a description of the interface. This might not be the (solemn) problem as our app can't even find the .h files from the library and they should at be least present.
   We really hope that we can avoid rewriting a lot of the code since the code base which needs to be ported is really large and (as usual) the deadline is close.

PS: We have so far only been working in Xcode 4.2 and have not tried with the command line tools yet.

Comment: Make sure you’ve specified the path to your library’s include files in your project/target’s build settings: Header Search Paths or User Header Search Paths.

Comment: Make sure that the header files are where you expect them to be (in the filesystem)

Comment: We have actually done this out of pure desperation and it sort of worked. But is this really necessary? I mean, that means that when you distribute the library you have to distribute the header files as well. So the .dylib does not work in a similar way as a .dll file in Windows which is completely self contained?

Comment: In this case, should we look into Frameworks in stead (which also package the header files if I understand correctly). What would the implications be when we want to use it in several apps?

Comment: @NobleK You don’t need to ship header files in your **application**. On the other hand, if you’re shipping your library for other developers to use, then yes, you need to ship header files as well, and you can use frameworks for that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Bavarious, it makes more sense now. If I understand you correctly the header files are only used to get the interface at compile time and are afterwords neither needed nor included? I guess it means that all the logic which is implemented in our .h files will be lost unless we move it to .cpp files? Is this also the case if we use frameworks or static libraries? Btw. could you please write your reply in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @NobleK that's not how c++ linkage works. in basic terms: definitions in headers of (nonstatic) inline functions will be copied to each object file they are visible to, the copies will be removed during linking. just make sure not to use the private extern and you should be ok in this regard. if the definition in header is not inline, it will likely produce a link error. functions/methods defined in a class body are implicitly inline. therefore, no, the information will not be lost, and you'll not have link errors as a result (assuming they can also build it out without issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

In this case, I would just add the directory containing the headers to the discovery paths for headers or libraries in Xcode. Depending on the layout, some approaches will be better than others.

Generally, you'll use some combination of:

- `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`
- `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`
- `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`
- or `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`

Which one is correct depends on the library you are using (e.g. these options can also affect the linker). When defining the discovery paths, you can add the suffix `**` to denote a recursive search.

This is ideal because you will have fewer troubles keeping your xc projects in sync with their vs solutions.

**Option 2**

Some people really like some drag and drop support for their includes... I don't, but this is the approach if there is so much disorganization that you can't just do something as simple as add a search path:

- add the headers you need to the project
- add those headers to the copy headers build phase of the target
- repeat until it builds and be prepared for breakage when you merge/pull their updates.

that gets messy quickly, and takes hours to reconstruct when you want to reuse the library if there are collisions in header names.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, both here and in your comment above.